# Rotation3D doesn't work properly in QML scene

Tags: 3d, rotation, qml, axis, scene

I am trying to rotate a complex 3D-object in QML around 3 different axes. For the sake of understanding here is a simplified code where you can rotate a cube by using sliders for the three different rotation angles. The first slider rotates the cube around the x-axis, the second slider around the y-axis and the third slider around the z-axis.

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import Qt3D 2.0
import Qt3D.Shapes 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0

Viewport {
    width: 500
    height: 500
    light: Light {
        ambientColor: "white"
        position: Qt.vector3d(5, 1, 10)
    }
    Cube {
        transform {
            Rotation3D {
                id: rotX
                axis: Qt.vector3d(1, 0, 0)
            }

            Rotation3D {
                id: rotY
                axis: Qt.vector3d(0, 1, 0)
            }
            Rotation3D {
                id: rotZ
                axis: Qt.vector3d(0, 0, 1)
            }
        }
    }

    Slider {
        id: sliderHorizontal1
        x: 37
        y: 21
        maximumValue: 360
        onValueChanged: rotX.angle = value
    }

    Slider {
        id: sliderHorizontal2
        x: 37
        y: 62
        maximumValue: 360
        onValueChanged: rotY.angle = value
    }

    Slider {
        id: sliderHorizontal3
        x: 37
        y: 104
        maximumValue: 360
        onValueChanged: rotZ.angle = value
    }
}
```

However when you try it out the cube in qmlscene sometimes rotates around his body fixed axes and sometimes around fixed axes in space (z-rotation for example is never around the body fixed axis).
I would like to rotate the cube **only** around its body fixed axes. How could I accomplish that?